# Change several columns of a dataframe to integer type. Error cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let it be the following Dataframe of pandas in Python:

| code | visit_1 | visit_2 | visit_3 S | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | True |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | False |
| 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | False |
| 2.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | True |
| 3.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | False |

I want to convert the first 4 columns of the above DataFrame to integer type:

```
cols = (df.filter(like='visit_').columns).append(df.filter(like='code').columns)
print(cols)
```

In the original DataFrame there are more columns, so I decided to create a filter by name of the columns I want to modify. I print on the screen what I get.

```
Index(['visit_1', 'visit_2',
       'visit_3 S', 'code'],
      dtype='object')
```

When I apply the type change to int, I get the following error:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda a: int(a), axis=1)

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

My idea is to obtain the following result:

| code | visit_1 | visit_2 | visit_3 | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | True |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | False |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | False |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | False |

I am grateful for any help you can offer me.

Comment: You don't need to use a lambda function, you can simply do "df[cols] = df[cols].astype('int64')" :) (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line of code to achieve the desired result. 
`df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda a:a.astype(int),axis=1)`